# Ember - how to render a view's property without html

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember view with the currentUrl property; this property gets the value when the view is called, like this:

```
{{view App.MyView currentUrl="www.website.com"}}
```

and in the view's template i have something like this:

```
<a href="{{view.currentUrl}}">
```

but this does not work because the output of handlebar expression is:

```
<script%20id='metamorph-4-start'%20type='text/x-placeholder'></script>www.website.com<script%20id='metamorph-4-end'%20type='text/x-placeholder'></script>
```

and not only www.website.com as I would like; do you know how can I get an output without the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the {{unbound}} helper here.

```
<a href="{{unbound view.currentUrl}}">
```

or the {{bind-attr}} helper

```
<a {{bind-attr href="view.currentUrl"}}>
```

depending if you want the property to be live updated (bind-attr) or not (unbound)